# Question on types of continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Determine if on the given interval, the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, is a) continuous b) uniformly continuous, c) Lipschitz continuous, d) differentiable, and e) $C^1$

The interval $(0, 1]$ and $[1, \infty)$

My work: Let $\epsilon > 0$ given. We must show there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $x,x_0 \in (0,1], \left|f(x)-f(x_0\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Thus $\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0}}\right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}}{\sqrt{xx_0}}\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{xx_0}}\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}\right|$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{xx_0}}\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}\right|<\epsilon$

$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}||\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}|<\sqrt{xx_0}|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}|\epsilon$

Note on the interval $\sqrt{xx_0}\leq1$ and $|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}|\leq2$,thus $|x-x_0|<2\epsilon$ and we set $\delta = 2\epsilon$ Therefore continuous.

b)  We also know that the function is uniformly continuous because our $\delta$  does not depend on x or $x_0$.

c) We can also conclude that the function is Lipschitz  continuous because $|x-x_0|<2\delta \Rightarrow |x-x_0|\frac{1}{2}<\delta$

d) ?

e) ?

Is this a sound argument? Also, my book offers no insight into parts d and e so, any help would be appreciated. Is any of this work transferable to $[1, \infty)$?

Comment: For part (c), a function is called Lipschitz continuous if there exists a constant $\lambda$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \lambda |x - y|$.

Comment: There is a mistake in your reasoning. For $x = \frac{1}{10000}$ and $x_0 = \frac{1}{100}$ we have $|f(x) - f(x_0)| = |100 - 10| = 90 > 2|x - x_0|$.

Comment: Is it possible to point me in the direction of the mistake?  Thanks

Comment: Plug in the numbers that I gave and see where things go wrong.

Comment: Your problem is that you worked the problem backwards.  Some of your steps cannot be reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the stage where you assume that 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{xx_0}}\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}\right|<\epsilon
$$
you are implicitly assuming that the function is uniformly continuous.  As @Arthur's example shows, this is a bad assumption.

To fix, notice that
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right| &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a})}\left|x-a\right| \\
& \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}|x-a|
\end{align*}
Where your assumption messed up was that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ can get rather big depending on $a$.

For part $(d)$ you can write down the definition of derivative, simplify things a bit and use the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

For part $(e)$ $C^1$ means that the derivative is continuous.  Once you've done $(d)$ you can use your limit definition to show that it is continuous.